# How to use wildcard characters in ts TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm coding a query in my NestTs project, so I would like to retrieve information matched with `LIKE` clause values.

The problem with my query is the table has three types of records `_INFORMED`, `_UNINFORMED` and `WITHOUT`. If I use the sentence

```
.where("user.firstName like :name", { name:`%_INFORMED%` })
```

... It matches with `_INFORMED` and `_UNINFORMED` records, then I tried to use the wildcard character as to standard SQL: `'%\\_INFORMED%'` but it looks wrong.

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Edit:

Full TYPEORM query:

```js
.createQueryBuilder(Stage, 's')
  .innerJoin('s.stageType', 'st')
  .leftJoin('s.reasons', 'r')
  .select(['s.id', 's.description', 's.name', 'st.id', 'st.name', 'st.displayName', 'r.id', 'r.code', 'r.description'])
  .where('st.name like :INFORMED', {
    INFORMED: '%\\INFORMED',
  })
  .orWhere('st.id = :eMeliKeyword', {
    eMeliKeyword: StageTypesID.DE_MELI_KEYWORD_ID,
  })
  .getMany();
```

Comment: what would be your full SQL statement ?

Comment: you should really define what you mean with "it looks wrong", what is the result and what is the expected result?

Comment: My query doesn't retrieve records. I execute the endpoint from postman but nothing error message appears